# Updated version of Adobe Reader

Tags: pdf, adobe

I'm not sure if this has been answered already...anyhow, I'm placing this question, so you could help.

I've been a PC user for as long as I can remember, and I've just migrated to Ubuntu. So far the product has delivered the satisfaction I am expecting.

However, there is one program that I'll need to ensure my productivity--an updated version of the Adobe REader.

Is there any way I could get this program via Ubuntu, without using WINE? please let me know... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adobe somehow drop their support to Ubuntu recently. The latest Adobe Reader for Ubuntu is 9.x. I have tried several other pdf readers, but none of them have comparable annotation functionality and compatibility with Windows machine comparing to Adobe Reader.

To use the latest version of Adobe Reader, there are probably only two ways you can do that. One is to set up a Windows virtual machine by using VMWare workstation or VirtualBox, and run the latest Adobe Reader in the VM.

Otherwise, you may reconsider to use Adobe Reader with Wine. Actually, I can run Adobe Reader 11.0 with Wine 1.7.18 in Uubntu 12.04 without any problem. You should be able to install it by following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318220/install-wine1-5-not-wine1-6).

Answer (score 0):

**No**. Adobe Reader is a proprietary software by Adobe, so only Adobe releases updates. Complain to them or switch to some other PDF viewer like [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/).